Axon-Mongo extension: Can I (and should I) go with "one tenant per collection"?
I am are using Axon Server/Framework for our event sourcing applications, and was tasked to use Axon-Mongo extension to use MongoDB as our embedded event store. (here is the Axon's documentation that I am using)
Using the Spring Boot Autoconfiguration option suggested in the link above, I can successfully store command services events in MongoDB. However, all of the events are stored in the "domainevents" collection. Our applications are multi-tenant with "row level" (meaning I have "tenant id" in all entities, events, queries; and I am using shared DBs, schemas, tables, etc.).
For example: this is what I currently have:
HOST:   somehost-cosmos-mongo.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:   
    |
    |   
    |__ MONGODB:    micro-serivce-ONE-db
    |   |__ domainevents collection     // all events of all tenants here
    |   |__ snapshotevents collection       
    |                   
    |   ...
    |__ MONGODB:    micro-serivce-TWO-db
    |   |__ domainevents collection     // all events of all tenants here
    |   |__ snapshotevents collection   

And I want to store each tenant's events in its own collection, like below:
HOST:   somehost-cosmos-mongo.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:   
    |
    |   
    |__ MONGODB:    micro-serivce-ONE-db
    |   |__ TENANT-1-domainevents collection    // TENANT 1's events here
    |   |__ TENANT-1-snapshotevents collection      
    |   |__ TENANT-2-domainevents collection    // TENANT 2's events here
    |   |__ TENANT-2-snapshotevents collection  
    |                   
    |   ...
    |__ MONGODB:    micro-serivce-TWO-db
    |   |__ TENANT-1-domainevents collection    // TENANT 1's events here
    |   |__ TENANT-1-snapshotevents collection      
    |   |__ TENANT-2-domainevents collection    // TENANT 2's events here
    |   |__ TENANT-2-snapshotevents collection  

    

Currently I can't find any documentation or sample code that suggests we can do or should do the "one tenant per collection" approach. From the Spring Boot autoconfiguration sample code provided by Axon, it seems that the database/name, domain-events collection/name, and snapshot-events collection/name are created that Spring Boot autoconfiguration time (which I can override the default names) but I can't dynamically create multiple collections at run-time and route new events to them (as I discover new tenants).
Your advice or suggestions are very much appreciated.
For reference, I am using Java 11, and the following pom dependencies:
<!--  Axon Mongo spring-boot "starter" dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework.extensions.mongo</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-mongo-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>


First and foremost, I am sorry to see you went without a reply for four months, @Peter.
Nonetheless, I want to give you some guidance on the subject of multi-tenant applications the follow the Event Sourcing paradigm.
Axon Framework also has a Multi-Tenancy extension, albeit focused on use with Axon Server.
The latter might not make it useable for you, but the thought process behind that extension could still help.
Axon Server has a feature called multi-context. This feature can be utilized to mirror the scenario of having multiple bounded contexts (a concept from DDD) to reflect your application landscape correctly.
The feature ensures that your Command Bus, Event Store, Event Bus, and Query Bus are completely separated per context. Hence, a setup with two contexts would have two buses of each type and two event stores. If you would mirror that concept with other infrastructure like MongoDB, you would thus have two dedicated domainevenentry buckets, one for each context.
Note that the feature is not called "bounded context"-support. This is done as the solution is useful for other scenarios as well.
The aforementioned Multi-Tenancy Extension uses multi-context support to make distinct buses and stores for each tenant you have. Thus, the contexts become your tenants. As it stands, I know of several teams that use this functionality successfully.
So, knowing that, I think you have roughly two options:

Use Axon Server with the Multi-Tenancy Extension, and you are virtually ready.
Configure a MongoDB-based EventStore for every tenant you have.

Either way, you would get the intended separation that tenants are not mixed.
In conclusion, I hope this helps you further, even though the reply might be a little late!
